# Java Android Values not being added to an Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am creating a **socket connection** with a client utilizing `android studio`. I can successfully make a connection between the mobile device and the server, and my first debug message `(Log.d("While Debugger", line))` successfully shows the input data from the server. However, the `arraylist` does not appear to adding the results, and my other debug messages are not providing any output! 
To clarify further, when I call the `returnData()` method the temperature array is returned as null.
Any help will be much appreciated, and I will do my best to answer any questions asked of what I've written. Thanks!

```
package com.mycompany.myfirstapp;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by seank on 15/07/2015.
 */
public class SocketExample {
    ArrayList<Double> temperature = new ArrayList<Double>();

public SocketExample() throws  IOException {

    String serverHostname = new String ("192.168.1.143");

    System.out.println ("Attemping to connect to host " +
            serverHostname + " on port 10007.");

    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    Log.d("Here", "Got to the streams");
    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, 10007);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
        Log.e("Here","Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                + "the connection to: " + serverHostname);
        Log.e("Here","Couldn't get I/O for "
                + "the connection to: " + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String line;
    while( (line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
        Log.d("While Debugger", line);
        Double value = Double.parseDouble(line);
        temperature.add(value);
    }

    if(temperature.size() == 0) {
        Log.d("Numbers", "size = 0");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Numbers", String.valueOf(temperature.size()));
    }

    if(String.valueOf(temperature.size()) == null) {
        Log.e("Numbers", "The temperature size is a null value");
    }
    // Close our streams
    in.close();
    out.close();
    echoSocket.close();
}

public ArrayList<Double> returnData() {
    return temperature;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SocketExample socket = new SocketExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post here some output that you get on `Log.d("While Debugger", line);` ? The line `String.valueOf(temperature.size())` always is not null.

Comment: Sure, it's just Double values - 07-16 09:32:11.634  18475-18475/com.mycompany.myfirstapp D/While Debugger﹕ 15.929024009466646
07-16 09:32:11.635  18475-18475/com.mycompany.myfirstapp D/While Debugger﹕ 15.545617386487134
07-16 09:32:11.635  18475-18475/com.mycompany.myfirstapp D/While Debugger﹕ 20.28877241271025
And so on

Comment: Can you check that `Double value = Double.parseDouble(line);` really parses line and value is not null? What about `\n` at the end of line?

Comment: I added another debug line under `temperature.add(value)` of `Log.d("Value Debugger", String.valueOf(value));`, which gave me the same debug messages as the "While Debugger" line. 
Forgive me being a noob, where would you add `\n` exactly and what for?

Comment: `line` is ended with `\n` (`\c\n`) character. This can cause some problems when parsing this string as double, but it's not that case probably. Are you sure you are calling `returnData()` within same instance, which is filled with content?

Comment: I'm calling the correct instance of `returnData()` , but as the answer has mentioned the size is being printed correctly in the while loop. I don't know how to fix this without a hack fix though...

Comment: OK, noticing this now, my last readline before it doesn't leave the loop is of all the doubles separated by a `.` . I'm going to try and find out why and I'll post it back here (If anyone's had that before feel free to let me know!), I thank all of you for helping me narrow down the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, your program is blocking in the while loop, so your next debug is not executed.

You can try to add below code into the your while loop

```
if(temperature.size() == 0) {
    Log.d("Numbers", "size = 0");
}
else {
    Log.d("Numbers", String.valueOf(temperature.size()));
}
```

Comment: You're completely correct! I'd have thought that this would cause an error and make the application hang or something? I'm not sure how to make it exit the loop without hacking a hardcoded solution though :(

Comment: change while( (line = in.readLine()) != null )  to  while( (line = in.readLine()) != "#" )  ,then it will exit the loop when you put in "#"

Comment: I think that counts as a hardcoded solution :P I need to figure out why the last line of data is a list of all the data in the array as one line, it can leave the `while` loop when I force it to on a `.size()` condition, but thank you :)